# Finding the index of integers on a list

Tags: python, list, integer, z-index

I have this list:

`L= ['p', 2, 3, 1,'T','F', 0,'L','C','H', 1,'C',0]`

What can i do to get all the positions of only integers, for example:
Integers positions are:
1
2
3
6
10
12

I tried converting the list to all int with
`[int(i) for i in L if type(i)== int or i.isdigit()]`
and then tried to index the result, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the next code snippet:

```
integer_positions = [index for index, value in enumerate(L) if isinstance(value, int)]

print("All integers:", " ".join(str(i) for i in integer_positions))
```

Here the `enumerate()` function is used to loop through the list and get the index of each element. Then the `isinstance()` function is used to check if the element is an integer. If it is, its index is added to the `integer_positions` list. Finally, the list of integer positions is printed as a string with `join()` and `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
L = ['p', 2, 3, 1, 'T', 'F', 0, 'L', 'C', 'H', 1, 'C', 0]

int_positions = [i for i in range(len(L)) if isinstance(L[i], int)] 
print("Integer positions are:", " ".join(map(str, int_positions)))
```

The `isinstance` function checks whether an object is an instance of a specific class or of a subclass of that class, and returns True or False.

Answer (score 0):

`i.isdigit()` won't work as `isdigit()` is a method for strings. This will work:

```
[i for i in range(len(L)) if str(L[i]).isdigit]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the list and check the data types as follows:

```
L= ['p', 2, 3, 1,'T','F', 0,'L','C','H', 1,'C',0]

print(*(i for i, n in enumerate(L) if isinstance(n, int)))
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 6 10 12
```

Comment: @Bhargav what do you need?

Answer (score -1):

You can typecast everything to `str` and then use [isnumeric](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isnumeric) with List Comprehension:

```
L= ['p', 2, 3, 1,'T','F', 0,'L','C','H', 1,'C',0]
L= [str(i) for i in L]
Final= [c for c,i in enumerate(L) if i.isnumeric()]
print(Final)
```

output #

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 12]
```

Comment: There are n ways to solve a problem...I'm posting whatevr i know

Comment: wdym? User want to find all int's what's with 5? ofc 5 will be included as its an int..User not mentioned ""'i need to exclude 5"""??

Comment: I got `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 12]` what's wrong in it?

Comment: OP doesn't mentioned any special case??? in his example he not used elemnts `int` typecatsed as `str` ...Then what's the use of rubbing special case??